# "child of" constraint does not rig properly

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints

I'm new here and to all of this, so I'm following a tutorial on YouTube, and I'm stuck on one part which seems simple in the video, but I've done something wrong and can't figure it out.

I have set up a series of bones along a leg, and they all rig properly. I can grab one end of the armature and all of the leg joints bend appropriately. I then set the "child of" constraint and the rigging doesn't work when I move the Parent in "object mode", but the whole leg moves as if no rigging is present.

This series of photos shows the leg flexing before the constraint is added (hope these link properly):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4e0N.jpg

The next set shows me trying to move the parent with the leg not flexing, but floating as if not rigged at all:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSCse.jpg

Probably not necessary, but here's the Constraints Properties:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfoQr.jpg

Obviously, I'd like the leg to bend while moving the Parent, as it does when selecting one end of the armature.

Comment: Hi Marakuyo and welcome to Blender SE. The most important thing new people should learn is, that we can only help you if we have all necessary informations to be able to help you. But of course there are also informations which should be provided  because they support us to help you e.g. by inserting the link to the tutorial (i know it's from Polyfjord because i listened, learned a lot as well and rebuild it) but a lot of other people here don't know that. And rigging can be a pretty complex process. There are happening a lot of things. So by just providing one or two settings...

Comment: ...this is not enough to really be capable to help you, but with this information you gave us, we can just guess. So if you want to help quick and precise help, i would recommend providing your blend file. You can do that by opening https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions.

Comment: and just to say it in general: Polyfjords tutorials are really amazing and a complete new level of (free) tutorials (that's only my personal opinion). They all work (i can say that, because i listened to all of them and rebuild 90% of them and they do work. So another way of solving your problem is: restart from the beginning, listen carefully to each step he does and do exactly (!!!) the same. Then it will work. Only do things another way if you are totally sure that it works the same. (i had to learn this by own experience)